# Using django ORM from non django python script

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is the scenario. I have Django project and python script project under a directory. The python script needs to runs independently on a scheduled time and also needs to access Database used by Django.

Is it possible to use/import existing Django code in python script to access db. If so how?

The idea comes for C# app where Models and data access layer can be built as library and can be used in many projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use just the ORM part of Django, without using the web parts.

The directory for your Django application will need to be in your `PYTHONPATH`, you'll have to explicitly set `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]`, and you'll have to import whatever models you want to use.  From there, you can create and update models as usual:

```
from myapp.models import Customer, Order
c = Customer.objects.create(name='John Smith')
orders = Order.objects.filter(customer__name='Mary Brown')
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and finally decided to implement a daemon in django custom command.
You can import anything django related there just as you would normally do in django code, while implementing your own code.